# What image was pressed (form)

Tags: php, html

So I have this form consisting of only of a few `<input type="image">`, but I'm having trouble retreiving the pressed image. Example:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="image" src="y1.jpg" name="y1">
    <input type="image" src="y2.jpg" name="y2">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['y1'])) {
        //Pressing the first image does not return this
        echo "You've pressed image y1!";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['y2'])) {
        //Pressing the second image does not return this
        echo "You've pressed image y2!";
    }
?>
```

I guess the problem lies somewhere in each image working like individual submit button for the same form, but one form for each image sounds like bad practice to me.

Probably missing something really silly here I know, and I'm sorry. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this:-

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['y1'])) {
        //Pressing the first image does not return this
        echo "You've pressed image y1!";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['y2'])) {
        //Pressing the second image does not return this
        echo "You've pressed image y2!";
    }

?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="image" src="y1.jpg" value="1" name="y1">
    <input type="image" src="y2.jpg" value="1" name="y2">
</form>
```

you just need value inside the input

Answer (score 0):

You can use var_dump($_POST) to check what you received.
In the case of image input without value it send position you click in image to server with _x, _y suffix.

If you just want to recognize what you click, add value like MuthaFury answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your input type is image so you can check easily because input name become name_x and name_y

```
if(isset($_POST['y1_x'], $_POST['y1_y']))
if(isset($_POST['y2_x'], $_POST['y2_y']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not assing a `value` attribute, the key exists in in the `$_POST` array, however, the content actually is *empty*.

Either set a value or check if the key exists.

```
if(key_exists('y1', $_POST))
```